# VB.NET Datagrid Calculations (Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagrid

In the datagrid table: calculate the difference between two columns with the result in third column (performed automatically during runtime). Null value is 0 in budget and cost columns. Budget - Cost = Difference. I am using Visual Studio 2010. If anyone knows how to do this in the designer, please let me know.Otherwise...

```
Budget = column7
Cost = column8
Difference = column 9
```

The budget column  less the cost column = difference column for all rows. Could someone please provide me with some code? I have trashed mine...not even worth posting.

Comment: You need to post the code that you have, then people can look at it and tell you what's wrong with it. Asking others to write code for you doesn't get you anywhere.

Comment: Are you using a `DataGridView` (on a WinForms app) or any other technology? What is your datasource (`DataTable`, or ...)? If you use a DataTable you can look at a calculated field ([`Expression` property of `DataColumn´](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using windowsforms:
Create a dataset using the designer
Create a datatable with three columns: budget, cost and a calculated column, difference.
Instantiate the  datatable and fill it.
Bind the datatable to your datagridview

Comment: Thanks for the answer~ I do not know how to create a dataset or a datatable...could you be more specific?

Comment: See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171897(v=vs.80).aspx for a walkthrough

Comment: Also look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3df0c8ey(v=vs.90).aspx to create calculated datacolumns

Answer (score 0):

You can create a database using Access or sql, then on your vb form at the top click data...add datasource, and then follow instructions.